How to prevent Blender from renaming appended objects' shared data blocks
I'm running into an issue with appending objects in Blender.
I have a file (File A) with several objects that share the same Geometry Nodes modifiers, Node Groups, and materials. When I append these objects one by one into another file (File B), Blender automatically renames the modifiers, Node Groups, and materials even though they have identical names and data.
To clarify, I've attached some images and a Blender file.
My question is: How can I prevent Blender from renaming these shared elements during append? I ideally want them to use the existing data in the new file (File B) so I can continue editing the object properties (curves, parameters) through the modifier panel.
It seems like linking the objects wouldn't work in this case, as I need to be able to make independent edits.



I think you may need to go to File Paths > Assets > Import Method and set it to Append (Reuse Data). This makes the appending via asset browser work in the way you're describing, but I'm not totally sure it works this way with appending straight from another blendfile.

Yup, the regular "Append" method will duplicate the data because it has no way to know for sure that the existing data blocks are exactly the same. You need to make your node tree an asset and use the asset browser in this case. Or use the "Link" system instead of "Append"

Thanks for these replies! Linking is not really option for me since I don't want all my files to depend completely on one original file.
When I use the asset browser, I encounter other problems. I think it is best I make a separate question for this.
